# Image disappears on setting width [Titanium]

Tags: image, titanium, width

I created an imageView in Titanium. Whenever I set the width and height of the image to "auto"; the image is not visible. But if I manually set height and width of the image, the image appears.

Why does this happen ?

```
 var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage:'test.png',
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto'
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go [here on the DOCs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-width) you will see that `auto is deprecated:

> 'auto' represents the default sizing behavior for a given type of view. The use of **'auto' is deprecated**, and should be replaced with the SIZE or FILL constants if it is necessary to set the view's behavior explicitly.

Instead try setting the width and height to `Titanium.UI.SIZE`, `Titanium.UI.FILL`, a pixel value, or a percentage of the parent view.